# Flutter doctor terminal command not working

Tags: android, flutter

$ Flutter doctor terminal command not working on ubuntu, giving error message "curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
"

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Assuming you have successfully downloaded and extracted [flutter_linux_v0.5.1-beta.tar.xz](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/beta/linux/flutter_linux_v0.5.1-beta.tar.xz) (latest update until now) onto your preferred directory.

```
export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Running this command in your ubuntu terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) adds flutter commands PATH variable to your system path for **temporary** session. As soon as you close the terminal, the system path is removed.

**In order for ubuntu terminal to remember flutter commands permanently, you need to:**

> 1.) open up terminal and cd to $HOME. for eg: user@linux:~$
>
> 2.) open the hidden file `.bashrc` with your desired editor. It resides in $HOME.
>
> 3.) add the following line
>   `export PATH=/home/yourname/flutter/bin:$PATH`
>   somewhere as a newline in `.bashrc` file preferably as a last line edit & save file.
>
> 4.) run `source /home/yourname/.bashrc` in terminal to process your recent changes.
>
> 5.) finally, run `echo $PATH` to see flutter dir is in your system path along with other such paths. for eg: `/home/yourname/flutter/bin`

Now close current terminal and reopen new terminal to check `flutter doctor`. It should process along with all other available flutter commands everytime now onwards. Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not Flutter nor "flutter doctor" specific, it's to do with curl. Googling this error seems to bring up results that are either related to;

- Virtualbox
- Networking
- Some combination of the above two

Answer (score 0):

Flutter depends on these command-line tools being available in your environment.

```
bash, mkdir, rm, git, curl, unzip, which
```

before working with flutter you need to install all of them .
if you want to install curl then write just

```
apt-get install curl
```

and similarly install all of them .
if they are available then upgrade them

Here is the source
https://flutter.io/setup-linux/
for lunix

Answer (score 0):

For **MAC** add below line in **.bash_profile** file  `export PATH=~/flutter/bin:$PATH;`